# automate tasks in safari and finder

Tags: finder, safari, automator

I'm trying to automate a right click, open image in new tab, select tab, drag image to a finder window and enter rename more od file.

I thought I'd by able to do this by creating a service on automator and then assigning it to a function key. I keep getting the "The action "watch me do" encountered an error" though and I'm at a loss.

I have enabled automator through accessability..

To clarify, I run a google image search, click on the correct image, then i'd like to be able to hit a function key in order to "right click, open image in new tab, select tab, drag image to a finder window and enter rename mode file"

I don't mind if the safari & Finder windows need to be in the same place and ready.

[image]

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail what exactly you want to automate (or to accomplish with the task you want to automate)? It seems as if you want to save an image from a website, but this is just my interpretation. Will it be only from one website, or generally? Also please share the Workflow you have so far.

Comment: I've edited post for clarification, it will be from multiple web sites, whichever the google search returns

Comment: In Safari Google Images, when you right click on the image it offers you to "Save Image as", no need to open it in new tab.

Comment: i still recieve a watch me do error when i try to automate that

Comment: ok, let me try your way

Comment: I would suggest throwing out your current method altogether, and JavaScripting the webpage from the Google Image result and saving a copy of the image directly to _Finder_ that way.

Comment: You must enable Safari in the accessibility preferences to get rid of the error. But I agree with @CJK, you should imagine a new workflow. Automating the right click is very likely to get you in trouble. Images are always changing sizes and position in the screen.

Answer (score 1):

**You must enable Safari in accessibility preferences too.**

Just as a suggestion, you could set your default download folder in Safari preferences to your desired folder, and automate just a key sequence (after right click and open image in a new tab):
 - control + Tab (change focus to the new tab)
 - Command + S (save image dialog)
 - Enter (confirm save)
 - Command + Tab (bring Finder up)
 - Enter (open rename mode)

And than you just type the name and hit enter.